# Chutzpah integration with TFS 2012

Tags: tfs, chutzpah

My team is trying to integrate Chutzpah into the TFS 2012 build process. We used [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah.aspx) as our starting point.

At a high level, the practical issue is that the Visual Studio Test Runner in the build agent context simply isn't finding the Chutzpah hooks. So while we can define `**\*.js` as a test source, without the Chutzpah bootstrapper actually being found and initialized, the test runner doesn't do anything with these files.

At a more detailed level, we are getting three concerning messages when we check the logs for loading the custom assemblies for the build controller:

```
Summary: There were 0 failures, 2 errors and 1 warnings loading custom activities and services.
Error: Method 'ToXml' in type 'Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter.ChutzpahAdapterSettings' from assembly 'Chutzpah.VS2012.TestAdapter, Version=2.2.0.171, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1ca802c37ffe1896' does not have an implementation.
Error: API restriction: The assembly '...\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\8c8e9402-1169-4782-99a9-ce42f83be8f0\A1288811191\Chutzpah\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll' has already loaded from a different location. It cannot be loaded from a new location within the same appdomain.
Warning: Could not load file or assembly '...\AppData\Local\Temp\VSTFSBuild\8c8e9402-1169-4782-99a9-ce42f83be8f0\A1288811191\Chutzpah\phantomjs.exe' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
```

Other than this information, we're more or less stuck. I'd love to hear from someone who has actually got Chutzpah running on a standalone 2012 build server so we can compare configurations.

Comment: Have you tried using the Chutzpah Nuget Package(http://nuget.org/packages/Chutzpah) instead of adding the assemblies to the custom assemblies path?

Comment: @Betty I tried it just in case, but I don't see how that would work - how would the test runner on the build agent get a handle to the Chutzpah test adapter in that setup?

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I do know the upcoming TFS Update 1 is meant to support that scenario - from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/10/29/visual-studio-2012-update-1-final-ctp.aspx - "Easier installation of unit test adapters on TFS build machines using Nuget"  can't find any more information on it right now.

Comment: It appears the chutzpah nuget package doesn't contain the test runner anyway. If you can wait then I'd recommend waiting for TFS2012 update 1 and for the Chutzpah Test Runner dev to support the new method.

Comment: Did you get this going in the end? update 1 is now out, although I haven't seen any information on the change that was meant to make this easier.  One last thing I did think of though was to double check which test runner was selected in the test run dialog.

Answer (score 1):

Error: API restriction: The assembly '....

Indicates that TFS is finding a dll in two different locations. You can change the pattern to Check and see if you have \*\**test*.dll as the value set for any test assemblies and change it to *test*.dll. This will prevent it loading it multiple times.

The other error might be because the test projects are not being rebuilt. 
Try re-building the test projects.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is not useful and is not even related to the details of the error message. The fact that you posted such a useless answer 90 minutes before the bounty expires makes me think you're trying to game for the points rather than actually help.

Comment: I was trying to help you resolve the problem by looking at the errors you provided. It is only help. How do you know that it is unrelated to your problem? I am not trying to game for points. Sorry if you took it this way.

Comment: Also, is it possible for you to compile the Chutzpah codebase on the build machine. The project source may help you find your solution. Are you able to get this working on other local machines.

Answer (score 1):

Actually Software Carpenter has a point, I believe what may be happening is your test spec for ordinary unit tests may be *test*.dll (or something similar) this means Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll is loaded as a unit test dll, then TFS tries loading it again when trying to run the chutzpah tests.

Try disable the normal unit test spec and see if it helps, if it does then change your spec to be something else (*test.dll) that doesn't incude TestPlatform.ObjectModel.dll.

Source: I just had the same error when trying to build a project with Test in its name.

Answer (score 1):

This discussion is also taking place on Codeplex.  Maybe some help can be provided there.

[Javascript Unit Tests on Team Foundation Service with Chutzpah](http://chutzpah.codeplex.com/discussions/400818)

Comment: Link is broken.  Per SO etiquette, please post the details in your answer (linking to a source is fine, but do still please post the actual answer).  Thank you.